# Removing an element in a linked list whose value is less than the next adjacent element

Tags: c, linked-list

Is there any error in this code? I am getting segmentation fault in this.
Question is about deleting elements whose value are less than the next element.

```
void Remove()
{
    struct Node* prev = NULL;
    struct Node* curr = head;
    struct Node* Next = NULL;
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
        Next = curr->next;
        if(curr->data < Next->data)
        {
            if(curr == head)
            {
                struct Node* temp2 = head;
                head = head->next;
                free(temp2);
                curr = head;
                //Next = curr->next;
            }
            else
            {
                struct Node* temp1 = curr;
                prev->next = curr->next;
                free(temp1);
                curr = Next;
                //Next = curr->next;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = Next;
            //Next = curr->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right away, there is an edge case.  What happens if the HEAD of the list needs to be removed because it is less than the 2nd element?  But in any case, you should tell us the inputs for which your code is failing.

Comment: First of all, try to come up with an algorithm on *paper*. Draw out a simple list on paper, and try to come up with a solution there first. Then when you implement it as code and it doesn't work as expected, you need to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Quote: `Is there any error in this code? I am getting segmentation fault in this` Well yes - if you get a seg fault, there is an error but not necessarily in this part of your program

Answer (score 1):

Here is one problem:

```
while(curr!=NULL)
{
    Next = curr->next;
    if(curr->data < Next->data)
```

When you reach the end of the list `curr->next` is NULL. So `Next` is NULL. Still you dereference it (i.e. `Next->data`), so your program will (likely) crash with a seg fault.

You must check for `Next` being NULL before you access `Next->data`